# A wedding planner has 5 bridesmaids and 5 groomsmen to arrange for a photo shoot. Determine the number of ways she can arrange them if:

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

1) They can stand anyhow

**My answer: 10!**

2) All the bridesmaid must be on the left, and all the groomsmen must be on the right

**My answer: 5! x 5!**

3) The bridesmaids must be kept together

**My answer: 5! x 6!**

4) She must start with a bridesmaid to the left and end with a groomsman to the right.

**My answer:1 x 8! x 1**

I feel like I'm missing something for number 4. My thinking behind it, is that there is bridesmaid on the left and a groomsman on the right, and the remaining people are organised in 8! ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1), 2), and 3) look OK to me.

As for 4), you can choose the bridesmaid on the far left in $5$ ways, and you can choose the groomsman on the far right in $5$ ways. The remaining $8$ people can be permuted in $8!$ ways between the bridesmaid and groomsman in the extreme positions. So I would say that $25 \cdot 8!$ is the correct answer to 4).